# Which Oracle query is faster

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-performance

I am trying to display employee properties using C# WPF view.

I have data in '2' different oracle tables in my database:

Those tables structure at high-level is...

- Employee table (`EMP`) - columns:

  ```
  ID, Name, Organisation
  ```
- Employee properties table (`EMPPR`) - columns

  ```
  ID, PropertyName, PropertyValue
  ```

The user will input 'List of Employee Name' and I need to display Employee properties using data in those '2' tables.

Each employee has properties from 40-80 i.e. 40-80 rows per employee in `EMPPR` table. In this case, which approach is more efficient?

Approach #1 - single query data retrieval:

```
SELECT Pr.PropertyName, Pr.PropertyValue
FROM EMP Emp, EMPPR Pr
WHERE Emp.ID = Pr.ID
  AND Emp.Name IN (<List of Names entered>)
```

Approach #2 - get IDs list using one query and Get properties using that ID in the second query

Query #1:

```
SELECT ID
FROM EMP
WHERE Name IN (<List of Names entered>)

Query #2:

SELECT PropertyName, PropertyValue
FROM EMPPR
WHERE ID IN (<List of IDs got from Query#1>)
```

I need to retrieve ~10K employee details at once where each employee has 40-80 properties.

Which approach is good?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2):

> Which query is faster?

The first one, which uses a single query to fetch your results.
Why? much of the elapsed time handling queries, especially ones with modestly sized rows like yours, is consumed going back and forth from the client to the database server.

Plus, the construct `WHERE something IN (val, val, val, val ... ... val)` can throw an error when you have too many values. So the first query is more robust.

**Pro tip:** Come on into the 21st century and use the new JOIN syntax.

```
 SELECT Pr.PropertyName, Pr.PropertyValue
   FROM EMP Emp
   JOIN EMPPR Pr ON Emp.ID = Pr.ID
  WHERE Emp.Name IN (<List of Names Inputted>)
```

Comment: Agree to that, databases do the job of "join" much better than letting it be done in the application layer/programme like the way you do in the second approach

Comment: Thank you all. Any performance improvement if we use JOIN syntax unlike mentioned in the question.

Comment: @UpendharSingirikonda - no there is no difference in performance. Many people find the explicit join syntax clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Use first approach of join between two tables  which is far better than using where clause two times.